# How to go throw a circle in libgdx, like ketchapp's hop hop hop or circle game

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I want to make an image object like an arrow, which will go through a circle.
I have seen some animations like what i am looking for is already implemented in Ketchapp's [hop hop hop game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lj8Qe_8DcwA)! or [Cicle game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqBjV5C7_H8)!
Please have a look at this video link and you will surely understand what i am looking for.

I have searched a lot but haven't found any libgdx resource that i could follow.

So please help me , if you have any solution regarding to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Draw separately further and closer parts of the circle. So you have to draw first further part, then arrow (ball, wire or what ever) and then draw closer part of the circle on top.